# Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

[image]

Please let me know why this happen and what is the solution.

Comment: Your Provisioning profile is not proper or might not exist. You need to register in the apple development centre to get this.

Comment: please look at the image link for more clarity. "enter image description here"

Comment: actually I created it many times but same problem exist

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1830/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your internet connection **[This might happen when it's verifying your app provisioning profile]**
2. Restart the Xcode and clean,build and do upload again.

> If 1 and 2 doesn't work, you might need to check your provision
>   profile that it's expire or not.

3. If they are not expired,you might have to remove the provision profile of both development and distribution from Xcode/Preferences/Your Account Detail/

[image]

> Then, download it again.
>
> Then, choose correct provision profile that you downloaded at Build
>   Setting.
>
> Close the Xcode.
>
> Open the Xcode and build again.

Good Luck!

Comment: provision profile not expired. I created it two days ago.

Comment: Hmm, was this happen when you upload the app to the app store after "Verifying App Assets..."

Comment: actually i just see that my provisioning profile is being invalid after few minutes. Is there any problem?

Comment: Actully the problem was in xcode. Because I opened it in 8.1 after that I used that code in 7.3.1 so thats why I faced this problem and Thanks for your help too.

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be a little bit simpler way to resolve the issue:

I unchecked Automatically manage signing and assigned profile manually, it stopped to complain about it.

[image: Xcode > General > Signing]

It seemed to work but actually, it has a problem to prevent update from previous installed app.

I dig it up a little bit more and found a solution to avoid it.

It is caused by you have unnecessary profiles in your library, so delete them manually.

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
```

Restart your xcode and archive then validate, it should be fine this time.

Comment: Deleting all my provisioning profiles in that path worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please check how are you archieving your code:

- Select your project in xcode(after play stop button on top)
- Change scheme to release.
- In your entitlement file make sure app-release has a value 'production'
- Archieve again and it should work

[image: [entitlement file for live/production ]]

[image: set scheme to release]